# Python missing or unusable error while cross compiling GDB

Tags: python, gdb

I get this error while attempting to cross-compile GDB (using the `--with-python` flag):

```
checking for python: /usr/bin/python
checking for python2.7: no
configure: error: python is missing or unusable
```

I made sure I had python2.7 installed in `/usr/bin`. I even removed the package and installed it again. I tried using `--with-python=/usr/bin` and `--with-python=/usr/local`, but no luck. I know for sure though that 2.7 is installed though. Any idea on what to do?

Comment: How did you solve this issue ? Following answers are not working for me . I have similar problem as yours

Comment: I honestly don't remember, sorry. :( It was 4 years ago when I had that problem...

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem on Debian 6.0 when compiling GDB 7.4.1

The solution was to install python headers

```
sudo apt-get install python2.6-dev
```

and then configure with the right flag

```
./configure --with-python
```

Comment: It worked in Ubuntu 12.04 compiling GDB 7.6. Installing python2.7-dev.

Comment: YMMD. On debian wheezy I had also to install python2.7-dev

Comment: apt-get install `python3.5-dev` works for me.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem with gdb 7.4 and finally made it worked after spending some time debugging.

By checking the file `<gdb-source-path>/gdb/config.log`, you will notice one line:

```
configure:11031: gcc -o conftest -g -O2   -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7   conftest.c -lncurses -lz -lm    -L/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config -ldl -framework CoreFoundation -lpython2.7 -u _PyMac_Error Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python >&5
```

Seems that the script `python/python-config.py` returned some invalid flags that caused the `gcc` command to fail.

The solution is to open `<gdb-source-directory>/gdb/python/python-config.py` and comment out these two lines:

```
#            if getvar('LINKFORSHARED') is not None:
#                libs.extend(getvar('LINKFORSHARED').split())
```

Comment: +1 It works. I compiled GDB 7.5.1 on OS X 10.6.8 without other problems.

Comment: Yep, this is the solution. Worked for me as well on OS X 10.6.8 when installing gdb 7.6.50.20130624 without having to install some other Python. I could just use my havily modified 2.7.5 install from python.org

Comment: Thanks for being verbose about how you debugged this. That was very helpful to me.

Answer (score 9):

I just came across a similar issue building gdb 7.8.1 using Continuum's Python 2.7, which, in my case, was installed in a non-standard location.

In this case, the solution was to provide an additional piece of configuration before running 'configure':

```
export LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,<non-standard-Python-lib-location> -L<non-standard-Python-lib-location>"
configure --with-python=<non-standard-Python-executable-location>
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to configure and compile python with `--enable-shared`.

Answer (score 7):

I hit this error building the ESP8266 SDK. Just did a 
sudo apt-get install python-dev 
and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

After many attempts, I managed to install gdb 13.1 on my ubuntu 22.04 by

```
 sudo apt-get install python3-dev

./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding my own solution since I cannot see it among the rest here. In my case I was able to solve this by using `configure` as follows:

```
./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python3
```

This was on a Ubuntu 22.04 machine. I suspect `--with-python` requires a full path to an existing python binary, so this seems like a much easier solution for standard distributions.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with almost the same error building gdb 13.0.50 with python 3.8 for a more recent udpate. Running make after `./configure --with-python` it shows python missing error.
During compilation it seems to be looking for `usr/bin/python` for python 3.8 while we only have `usr/bin/python3`.

So I quickly changed the name of the python directory from `usr/bin/python3` to `usr/bin/python` and it compiled and found python successfully.

Don't forget to change it back for dependencies