# Python missing or unusable while compiling gdb under Cent OS 5

Tags: python, python-2.7, gdb, makefile

I checked this question and it is not applicable.
[Python missing or unusable error while cross compiling GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792844/python-missing-or-unusable-error-while-cross-compiling-gdb)

I'm trying to build gdb 7.5 with python support on Cent OS 5.

```
configure --with-expat --with-python
```

Does not log any errors and the Python devel files are installed.

I set `LDFLAGS="L/usr/local/expat-2.1 -L/opt/python27/lib`

`/opt/python27/lib` contains:

```
rwxrwxrwx  1 root root      19 Mar 14 15:35 libpython2.7.so -> libpython2.7.so.1.0
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root root 1893448 Aug 30  2012 libpython2.7.so.1.0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Mar 14 15:35 pkgconfig
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root   20480 Mar 14 21:49 python2.7
```

Running `make` produces this error:

```
checking whether to use python... yes
checking for python... /opt/python27/bin/python
checking for python2.7... no
configure: error: python is missing or unusable
```

`/opt/python27/bin/python` exists has the correct permissions and is executable.

Why can't the link process find python?

Comment: You need to read `config.log` and find out what exactly has failed.

Comment: There are no errors in config.log.

Comment: Then you are reading the wrong config.log.

Comment: I've looked through all 13 config.log and the there errors are either:
- the standard choke errors
- ac_nonexistent.h errors which don't affect compilation
- conftest.c errors which don't apply to this compilation

Where would you suggest looking?

Comment: You should read only one config.log, in the build directory.

Comment: That is the first place I looked and it only has the choke error.

Comment: Then you failed to find the lines related to the "checking for python2.7" test

Comment: Your conjectures on what I might not have done are not helpful and don't address the issue..  Please, read the orignal post.  Configure has the correct path and config.log registers this.  There is not explicit check for the Python binary in the configure process.   The line "checking for python... /opt/python27/bin/python" points to the binary and it exits and is executable.

Comment: "checking for python" and "checking for python2.7" are different checks. You may think anything about my suggestions but they are the only thing I may offer you with the data we have.

Comment: python2.7 also exists and is in the PATH.

Comment: So what? You still don't know what exactly did the configure check.

Answer (score 3):

The next line AFTER the `configure: error:` line should be something like:

```
make[1]: [configure-gdb]: ....
```

telling you that this error comes from running configure in the gdb subdirectory.  So you should look in the `config.log` file there.  This should show you something that configure tried to do that failed -- probably a chunk of C code that failed to compile, with an error message from the compiler something like 'can't find include file "Python.h"'.  This tells you what the problem is -- it couldn't find the python header file used to embed python in gdb.

Now your problem may be slightly different, but its probably related to not having the python embedding components properly installed.

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't the link process find python?

It's not the *link* process; it's the configure process in one of the subdirectories.

Find out which subdirectory it is (`make` should say `Leaving directory XXXX`), and look in `config.log` in that subdirectory for what went wrong.

> The reason I posted is that config.log does not point to a problem, yet when I run make I receive the error from the original post

The `make` process runs *additional* `configure` processes. Your error is *clearly* from that additional process. You claim to have checked all `config.log`s in all subdirectories, but that appears unlikely given the symptoms you've described.

Comment: This is the one that I checked first and the only error is the choke error. I then checked all the others to see if they would contain a clue. The reason I posted is that config.log does not point to a problem, yet when I run make I receive the error from the original post.

Comment: @Robert I've updated the answer; hopefully to make it clearer what is (or at least appears to be) happening.

Comment: Thanks for updating the reply.  So, "make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rhancock/Downloads/gdb-7.5'.  The config.log in this directory has the last line "configure: exit 0".  A search of the file for "error" shows only the choke error. A case insensitive search for "python" shows only the contents of LDFLAGS and the literal command line switch "python".

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for making you wait 10 years for an answer.

In my case I looked under the `gdb/config.log` file and found this:

```
configure:10369: checking for python2.7
configure:10387: gcc -o conftest -g -O2 -I/home/user/stevie-bsp/toolchain-build/builds/destdir/aarch64-host-linux-gnu/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc  conftest.c -ldl -lncursesw -lm -ldl  -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -lpython2.7 -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions >&5
conftest.c:54:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
   54 | #include "Python.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Looks like it is a misleading error message when the Python 2 headers aren't installed. I fixed that on Ubuntu with `apt install python2-dev`; on CentOS the package name would vary.

Secondly, the command `python` must start the Python 2 interpreter. The build process will not give a clear error about this and silently fails to query the include path for the Python headers. I resolved it by using the `python-is-python2` package on Ubuntu. I'm not sure about CentOS but in the worst case you can create a symlink.